# How to get screen resolution and save it to a text file?

Tags: vbscript, screenresolution

I found the following vbs script to get the screen resolution

but I would like to save the result in a text file please help me

```
    Dim HTM, wWidth, wHeight
    Set HTM = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    wWidth = HTM.parentWindow.screen.Width
    wHeight = HTM.parentWindow.screen.Height
    wscript.echo wWidth & "X" & wHeight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save it to a new text file you may want to use following VBScript for your needs.

```
Dim HTM, wWidth, wHeight
Set HTM = CreateObject("htmlfile")
wWidth = HTM.parentWindow.screen.Width
wHeight = HTM.parentWindow.screen.Height
wscript.echo wWidth & "X" & wHeight

Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\file.txt",2,true)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine("--- screen resolution start -------------------------")
objFileToWrite.WriteLine( wWidth & "X" & wHeight)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine("--- screen resolution end   -------------------------")
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
```

If you want to append text to the end of an existing text file you can easily change the IOMode parameter to `8` e.g.

```
("D:\file.txt",8,true)
```

The `true` parameter makes sure that the file is newly created or must already exist if `false`.

Comment: @frankell: nice to have helped - you may accept the answer when this is a solution to your problem.

Comment: ops I just noticed I only checked the up triangle vote now I clicked also on the "accept" sign, thanks again !